# Restify GET request body

Tags: javascript, node.js, restify

I am building a rest api using restify and I need to allow post body in get requests. I am using bodyparser but it gives only a string. I want it to be an object like in the normal post endpoints.

How can I turn it in to an object? Here is my code:

```js
const server = restify.createServer();
server.use(restify.queryParser());
server.use(restify.bodyParser());
server.get('/endpoint', function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(typeof req.body);
    console.log(req.body && req.body.asd);
    res.send(200);
});
```

Comment: "I need to allow post body in get requests" — That is a pretty bizarre need. The HTTP specification warns against making GET requests with payloads. Designing your system around them is an odd choice.

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]. You seem to have provided all the required server side code, but not the input you expect it to handle. What does the request look like? In particular, what is the Content-Type header and what is the request body? (And have you confirmed you are generating them correctly?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bodyParser in restify doesn’t default to parsing valid JSON (which I assume you are using) for the body of requests that are using the **GET** method. You have to supply a configuration object to the initialization of bodyParser with the *requestBodyOnGet* key set to true:

```js
server.use(restify.bodyParser({
    requestBodyOnGet: true
}));
```

To ensure that the body of the request will be JSON, I would also recommend you to check the **content-type** in your endpoint handler; e.g:

```js
const server = restify.createServer();
server.use(restify.queryParser());
server.use(restify.bodyParser({
    requestBodyOnGet: true
}));
server.get('/endpoint', function (req, res, next) {
    // Ensures that the body of the request is of content-type JSON.
    if (!req.is('json')) {
        return next(new restify.errors.UnsupportedMediaTypeError('content-type: application/json required'));
    }
    console.log(typeof req.body);
    console.log(req.body && req.body.asd);
    res.send(200);
});
```